# Does Freedom of Movement allow you to move normally in a storm created by magic?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, movement

Freedom of Movement States:

> This spell enables you or a creature you touch to move and attack normally for the duration of the spell, even under the influence of magic that usually impedes movement, such as paralysis, solid fog, slow, and web.

The control winds spell says:

> You alter wind force in the area surrounding you. You can make the wind blow in a certain direction or manner, increase its strength, or decrease its strength. The new wind direction and strength persist until the spell ends or until you choose to alter your handiwork, which requires concentration. You may create an “eye” of calm air up to 80 feet in diameter at the center of the area if you so desire, and you may choose to limit the area to any cylindrical area less than your full limit.

If a character is under the effect of a freedom of movement spell are they still effected by an increase in wind speed that could knock them down or check them or no?

Comment: Are you already familiar with [this question?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/32233/8610) (Seriously, spells don't get much vaguer than *freedom of movement*.)

Comment: I'm not convinced the answer to this question depends on if the storm is created by control winds.  However, I also don't know the answer=)

Comment: @joedragons Nor should you be so convinced! The syntax of *freedom of movement* means that the affected creature "move[s] and attack[s] normally for the duration of the spell"—everything after the *even*? Embellishment. (Cf. *You can light a fire even underwater* which doesn't mean you can *only* light fires underwater!) The spell *freedom of movement* is, to put it mildly, a bit broad in its mandate.

Answer (score 1):

From a RAW Stand point we have this:

1. Freedom of movement prevents effects that would cause you to be
   unable to move freely, such as solid fog, paralizys, grapple, etc.
2. Freedom of movement **does't** prevent you from beeing **bullrushed, blown away or tripped.**
3. The spell control winds allow's you to control the speed and direction of the winds, wich in return is capable of provoking some effects on creatures based on the wind force and the size of said creatures.
4. The checked condition prevent's you from moving

So based on this we have the situation where a creature under freedom of movement would not be checked by the winds, but would be blown away or knocked down provided that the wind is strong enough to do so because freedom of movement doesn't prevent you from beeing moved by other effects, it merely allows you to move freely if something would prevent you to do so.

Also from the 3.5 FAQ:

> Can prone characters move?
>
> The rules on crawling would obviously apply here, but this question
>   also includes things like limbless creatures and oozes.   If a
>   creature has no motive limbs, you move at your normal speed when
>   prone, otherwise you must crawl.

Comment: “Freedom of movement does't prevent you from beeing bullrushed, blown away or tripped,” err... mightn’t it? The wording on *freedom of movement* is preposterously broad. It just says it allows you to move and attack normally... period. So maybe you can get knocked down, but being prone can’t actually impede your attacks or movement in any way... There kind of *has to be* a limit to this somewhere, but unfortunately where that limit lies is not really clear from the description of *freedom of movement*. Anyway, you might either want to give the text more attention, or else soften your claims.

Comment: @KRyan well I based my answer from the specific text of the spell wich I agree with you is somehow vague but my claims stands true since there isn't anything that states otherwise on the spell. Also from the 3.5 FAQ Can prone characters move? The rules on crawling would obviously apply here, but this question also includes things like limbless creatures and oozes.   If a creature has no motive limbs, you move at your normal speed when prone, otherwise you must crawl.

Comment: I’m sorry, but that contradicts *freedom of movement*’s text, and while it might be a reasonable place to put a limit on the text of an over-broad, vaguely-worded spell, making an objective claim about what it does or doesn’t do based not on text but on where you would personally limit the spell is problematic. That FAQ doesn’t address *freedom of movement*, and in any event [the FAQ is highly problematic](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/4563) and is widely considered to not be a reliable rules source.

Comment: On a completely separate note, please indicate put large quotations in quote boxes by starting each paragraph with `>`, thanks. I’ve edited that in for you a few times, but at this point you need to learn to do so yourself.

Comment: @KRyan oh, didn't realized I could do it. Thanks again, like I said I'm still learning some formatting and I appreciate all the tips you are giving me, gonna try  to improve from now on.

Comment: it does not prevent you being bullrushed moved or tripped.
It allows you to move freely, but not necessarily free to resist movement. That said, being tripped my not be an issue, since by the vague wording you very well may be able to move freely while prone.

Comment: @KRyan I don't agree that it contradicts Freedom of Movement's text.  Prone and forced move aren't preventing the person from moving.  It prevents magic that impedes movement, it allows instant escape from grapples, and it allows normal move and attack underwater.  The prone state isn't magical, even when caused by a magical effect, any more than ones location would be magical after forced movement.  If you want to stop being prone, you don't wait for a duration or a saving throw, you stand up.

Answer (score 0):

A storm is likely a difficult terrain modifier, and as such is almost definitely ignored by freedom of movement.

We can get into a deep argument about what raw allows or disallows. Terrain is one that is very typically affected by freedom of movement (and in fact in later editions it was explicitly added in the spell definition)

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetical situation,

character is crossing over wild river. He casts freedom of movement.

Will he cross over, ignoring the strong current of the river or will river carry him away?

I would say he will cross and current will have no effect on him. But why would then Control wind spell blow him away? I mean I tried to cross over such river (IRL), I managed to do it but I was more than hundred meters downstream. Force of water and air are "same", but different element.

In other hand, there is no clear description/rule what forces of nature Freedom of Movement negates.

So, to conclude, I would suggest that your GM/DM should decide what are the limits of Freedom of movement in your campaign.

Answer (score -6):

First of all, I should warn @Khaldhool that this answer is based mostly on speculation and in part uses an absence of a statement (instead of a positive statement) as a proof. But I believe it may be usefull.

Underwater part of freedom of movement spell would be a starting point here. While you move and attack normally under the effect of freedom of movement underwater, it isn't stated you ignore water current.

Now in the air you already move and attack normally, but your question is basically if you can ignore air current. I believe those two are similar enough. So generally wind would affect you.

Checked is probably a specific case, if a creature under freedom of movement isn't a flying one. Checked condition specifically limits your movement on your turn so it should be negated by freedom of movement. Flying creatures just moved back once per turn, and presumably may otherwise act normally, so they don't care if they have a spell functioning on them or not.

To support my point further, creatures under freedom of movement effect aren't immune to bullrush and trip, which are somewhat similar to Blown Away and Knocked Down effects of winds.